# How to understand "unparkSuccessor" function on AQS

Tags: java, concurrency

When I read Java's source about AQS(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer),I got a doubt.

```
private void unparkSuccessor(Node node) {
    /*
     * If status is negative (i.e., possibly needing signal) try
     * to clear in anticipation of signalling.  It is OK if this
     * fails or if status is changed by waiting thread.
     */
    int ws = node.waitStatus;
    if (ws < 0)
        compareAndSetWaitStatus(node, ws, 0);

    /*
     * Thread to unpark is held in successor, which is normally
     * just the next node.  But if cancelled or apparently null,
     * traverse backwards from tail to find the actual
     * non-cancelled successor.
     */
    Node s = node.next;
    if (s == null || s.waitStatus > 0) {
        s = null;
        for (Node t = tail; t != null && t != node; t = t.prev)
            if (t.waitStatus <= 0)
                s = t;
    }
    if (s != null)
        LockSupport.unpark(s.thread);
}
```

the main doubts are :

```
if (s == null || s.waitStatus > 0) {
    s = null;
    for (Node t = tail; t != null && t != node; t = t.prev)
        if (t.waitStatus <= 0)
            s = t;
}
```

why if cancelled or apparently null,traverse backwards from tail to find the actual non-cancelled successor? rather than from head to find the actual non-cancelled successor?
Thank for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a conservative design. The `next` is assigned in `enq` method, setting the new tail and linking previous tail's `next` reference to the new tail is not an atomic operation. In the for loop, it first assigns prev field  and if wins the `compareAndSetTail`, then assign the `prev`'s next to the new tail node.
So the `next` path is an optimization if `next` is not null and `next` is not canceled, as opposed to traversing backwards.

> So seeing a null next field does not necessarily mean that node is at end of queue.
>   The next field of cancelled nodes is set to point to the node itself instead of null, to make life easier for isOnSyncQueue.

```
private Node enq(final Node node) {
    for (;;) {
        Node t = tail;
        if (t == null) { // Must initialize
            if (compareAndSetHead(new Node()))
                tail = head;
        } else {
            node.prev = t;
            if (compareAndSetTail(t, node)) {
                t.next = node;
                return t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```